# What does this phrase apply to?

Tags: meaning

> User A is playing this game on XX **defeated 5% of all gamers**.

I read this from an app, and XX refers to a platform. Does the bold part apply to "this game"? Which means:

> User A is playing this game on XX, and this game has defeated 5% of
>   all gamers.

Comment: I think some additional context, like the source, could be helpful.

Comment: Yep, without context it could mean that player has defeated 5% of all gamers of that game on that console.

Comment: Not the game, but the player has defeated 5% of all gamers